# Member of Distribution Group not receiving emails in A/D->AZURE CONNECT Integrated Infrastructure

Tags: entra-id

Just started as IT Director at a firm about a month ago. Running two Windows 2016 A/D DCs (simple forest, single domain). Prior IT staff has it integrated with Azure AD using a preconfigured AD CONNECT configuration.

I recently created a new contact in our AD for a user. This Contact has their email address specified in our on prem A/D.

I added this AD Contact (on prem) to a distribution group called All Staff using ADUC. They are a member.

When I go into my Azure A/D online and look at that group, this person's email address does NOT show up as being a member of AllStaff@MYDOMAIN.Com

Pulling my hair out. There are no sync errors having anything to do with her contact address (email).

I'm not sure where to look next. Ideas?

Comment: Deleted my answer, because it was actually wrong. But I'll add one of the responses to your comments: I think you need to clarify what you are trying to achieve and what object types you are working with. In the question you write that you want to add a contact to a distribution list. In your last comment you say she has a mailbox. And what does that mean, exactly: "her email addr doesn't exist without a contact card"?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify:

1. You created an on premises Contact in ADUC.
2. You added this Contact to an on premises Distribution Group in ADUC.
3. You verified that this Contact synchronized to Azure AD/Office 365.
4. You verified that this Distribution Group is actually synced from on premises.
5. You do not see this Contact as a member the Distribution Group in Azure AD/Office 365.
6. You do not see any errors in the Azure AD Connect Synchronization Service management console.

Double check the following:

Is this Distribution Group actually synced from on premises or is it a "cloud only" Distribution Group? You can quickly see this if you add the "Sync Status" column.

Is this Contact listed in Contacts in the O365 admin center?

Do you see this Contact in the Exchange admin center?

Does the Contact show as being synced from on premises or is it a "cloud only" Contact.

If you confirm all of this, then open a support case with Office 365. They'll help you troubleshoot this. Office 365 support is always free of charge.